# Upper case for single array field using strtoupper

Tags: php

I would like to upper case specific field in my array.

from "en" => "ENGLISH" to "EN" => "ENGLISH"

$officialLanguages array:

```
array:1 [      
  "en" => "ENGLISH"      
]



 dd($officialLanguages = array_map('strtoupper', $officialLanguages['lang_id']));
```

Gives me below error

> Undefined index: lang_id.

Comment: show your full code, what this `$officialLanguages` contains.

Comment: That isn't simply a field in your array, it's the key to an element in your array: `$officialLanguages = array_combine(array_map('strtoupper',array_keys($officialLanguages)), $officialLanguages);` I'd really suggest learning a bit about PHP arrays, because lang_id sounds like your database column.... and however your'e manipulating the data retrieved from the database subsequently, you're not using database column names any more

Comment: @MarkBaker

Works like a charm!
Yes, it's indeed my DB column.

Answer (score 0):

use this 
[array_change_key_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php)

```
    $input_array = array("FirSt" => 1, "SecOnd" => 4);
    print_r(array_change_key_case($input_array, CASE_UPPER));
    //result
    Array
    (
        [FIRST] => 1
        [SECOND] => 4
    )
```